# How can I display documents from multiple document libraries

Tags: web-part, document-library

How can I display documents from multiple document libraries all in one list , "without developing a specific web part"

Answer (score 3):

Easy as pie, you just use a search resultat web part, set it to display only documents and only from the specific libraries (by specifying the path)

Comment: Guess this is the only way with regard to Out of box methods.

Answer (score 1):

The **Content Query Web Part** (CQWP) can also be used.  This is a good overview article from Microsoft comparing the CQWP and the Content Search Web Part:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929